# Laravel: editing two tables

Tags: laravel

I'm wondering how would it be possible to edit two tables at the same view. 
I've got 2 models which are related to eachother.

In my view I'm trying to repopulate my Form select with already inserted value in order to alter it.

**Models**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
protected $table = 'products';

public $primaryKey = 'id';

public $timestamps = true; 

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function material()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Material');
}

}
```

---

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Material extends Model
{
protected $table = 'material';

public $primaryKey = 'id';

public $timestamps = true; 

function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Products::find($id);

    return view('products.edit')->with('product', $product);
}
```

**View(products.edit)**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@include('inc.messages')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Edit</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['ProductsController@update', $product->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title', $product->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
            {{Form::textarea('body', $product->body, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body text'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('material', 'Material') !!}
            {!! Form::select('material',dd($Materials), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>



        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>

@endsection
```

**Error output**
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\material\resources\views\products\edit.blade.php)

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use?

Comment: Hi, lewis4u. I'm using Laravel version 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to repopulate a select box in Laravel you need to have possible options that a user can select and then make a select box like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('material', 'Material') !!}
    {!! Form::select('material', ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

And that option 1,2,3 array can also be called from a database.

P.S.  you should use {!! !!} endings instead of {{ }} for `{!! Form !!}` facade.

#### update

---

in order to have the options of select box from database you need to use pluck() to get them.

Make a new function in your controller:

```
public function materials()
{
    return DB::table('your_table')->pluck('name', 'id');
    // or this ↓
    return ModelName::pluck('name', 'id');
}
```

and then in your `create` and `edit` functions pass it through like this:

```
public function create($id)
{
    $product = Products::find($id);
    $theMaterials = $this->materials();

    return view('products.create')->with('product', $product, 'materials', $materials);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Products::find($id);
    $theMaterials = $this->materials();

    return view('products.edit')->with('product', $product, 'materials', $materials);
}
```

#### update

---

```
{!! Form::model($product, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ProductController@update', $product->id]]) !!}
```

Comment: Hi, lewis4u. The values are already stored in my DB which should be present in the form select. When I'm in Edit view it should populate the select with stored value which was selected on row creation.

Comment: I've created another function. Added it to edit function but still somewhy I'm receiving an error: Undefined variable: Materials (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\material\resources\views\products\edit.blade.php)

Currently my select form: 
{!! Form::select('material',$Materials, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

Comment: Try to dd($Materials) and make sure you are passing it from the controller

Comment: Oh and please show your form how does it look like. Just the first line for edit and create

Comment: Yeah for edit you need to use Form::model something like this `{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ArticlesController@update', $article->id]]) !!}`

Comment: Updated the form::open to form::model. But somewhy it's still returning an error that the variable is not defined.

Comment: lewis4u, I've found the problem but don't know how to fix it.

I can't pass multiple parameters with return. The first one only get's assigned. Is it possible to return an array of $products and $materials?

return view('products.edit')->with('product', $product, 'materials', $materials); <--- this is not working

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: yes it is...you car return an array ... then you need to use foreach loop to show them all

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want to return.... the edit view should only have one $product to edit it. and if you want to show an array in view just do `@foreach($materials as $material) <li>{{ $material }}</li> @endforeach`

Comment: I want to populate the {!! Form::select('material', ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} with pre-selected value from DB. But I should be able to change it and the materials array should be listed.